# nav2 commander API waitUntilNav2Active waits forever

Tags: nav2

I am trying to use the nav2 commander API to command a Gazebo robot to follow a set of waypoints like so:

```
nav = BasicNavigator()
nav.waitUntilNav2Active()
p = Pose()
p.position.x = 1
p.position.y = 1
p.position.z = 0
p.orientation.x = 0
p.orientation.y = 0
p.orientation.z = 0
p.orientation.w = 1
nav.followWaypoints([p])
```

However, the `nav.waitUntilNav2Active()` call never terminates and the following log message repeats forever.

```
[namoros-8] [INFO] [1711535604.039628359] [namoros.namoros_main]: amcl/get_state service not available, waiting...
```

What is strange is that I also see log messages that amcl has been activated:

```
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1711535314.225494605] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Activating amcl
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1711535314.225844927] [amcl]: Activating
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1711535314.225880023] [amcl]: Creating bond (amcl) to lifecycle manager.
```

I am also able to do successfully waypoint following via rviz:

[image]

Any ideas why it is not working via the commander API? Thanks for your time!

System setup:

- Ubuntu22.04
- ROS2 Iron
- Gazebo Fortress

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the PF visualized in rviz, I don't think that it is up and ready to rock and roll? Cherry picking the logs makes it hard for me to tell. Have you namespaced or remapped anything? I also noticed that you never set the initial pose, that is required in ROS 2, we don't assume any starting pose until you tell us, as all the demos show: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_simple_commander/nav2_simple_commander/demo_inspection.py#L55

Comment: What is the PF?

Comment: I tried setting the initial pose, but same issue. I found that if I edit `nav2_simple_commander/robot_navigation.py` and add a `/` to each action name, it starts working. But that is obviously a hack and not a suitable solution.

Comment: Particle filter

Comment: I'm using odometry only, so I don't care about the particle filter. Anyways, that is not the problem. There is a namespace issue, but I am not using a namespace nor remapping anything. Please see my second comment above.